# How do you reply to a seller on Amazon?

Tags: amazon

I sent a seller a message, they replied asking me something, I wanted to reply.

But I see no link to do so in the email, and I cannot see where to on Amazon's site

Where is the option?

Comment: I'll just add this comment from heera lal 'cos it's pretty good "this is my contact number 9414746068"

Comment: @bummi 'cos it's a good joke

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't directly email the seller because Amazon wants messages stored on their system for arbitration or dispute resolution.

So, you have to contact your seller through Amazon.

Go to "your account" > "your orders".  There should be a button that says "Contact Seller".

Another way is to click on the "order details" or order number.  Then find and click on the seller's name.  It should be a hyperlink that opens to web form.

Lastly, you can go to the seller's storefront.  Then on their "about" page, there is a "Contact the seller" link under "Further Information" on the bottom right.

Comment: thanks, i see it now, in "your orders". I know you can't email the seller directly, I just meant the email one gets from amazon with the seller's message, didn't have a link for me to click to reply, but now I see where to contact the seller.

Comment: to get the front of the sellers store.. click used and new, then the sellers name, and I see something like this when I scroll down http://i.imgur.com/xseUgX2.png   then a link on the bottom , I was looking for "further information" or "about" but it says about returns and exchanges and there's an about page from there. You can also google the name of the seller with "further information" and the amazon seller about page comes up. with "detailed seller information"

Comment: Well the question is whether by generating a new message the seller can link the reply with the former message

Comment: To reply to an existing message,  Select Your Account / Message Centre then select the Buyer/Seller Messages

Comment: @AdamPatterson Thanks.  You may wish to post what you've said as a separate answer.

But it is puzzling that Amazon doesn't include a 'reply' link in the email generated from the seller's message.

Comment: @Stewart I don't have the reputation to do so here :(

Comment: Just realised this is a protected question - sorry about that.  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user
Note in particular "10 reputation points *from participating on this site*" - so association bonus doesn't count. :(

Answer (score 9):

Here: https://www.amazon.com/gp/communication-manager/inbox.html

Note also that Amazon has some aggressive code to hide your attempts to include your email addresses within the messages.

Comment: This is actually better method than using "Contact seller" from Orders. "Contact seller" start a new conversation; whereas, this method keep the history of the conversation thread.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for... I needed to reply to a thread with a seller on amazon.ca, so I just edited the URL so the domain was www.amazon.ca, it worked perfectly. I can't promise this will work for all Amazon country variants, but I bet it does.

Comment: This is what I needed as well. Couldn't find a link in the account page.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I can't reply to a message I receive.

Answer (score 1):

You can reply to a seller’s email by hovering your mouse on the *Your Account* link (top page on the right) and from the drop down menu click again on **Your Account**. In the first table, called *Orders*, if you look to the right, there's a heading in bold: **More Order Actions** and some links under it—the last link says **Your E-mails With Sellers**. Click on it and you'll be able to reply directly to the seller's email.

Comment: This option is not there anymore!

Comment: This navigation does not seem to exist anymore. I did this: "Accounts & Lists" -> In "Email alerts, messages, and ads" box -> "Message Centre" -> "Buyer/Seller Messages" then click on one of the messages and click "Reply". You can reply and add various types of files.