# How to contact seller when there is no Contact option?

Tags: amazon

I've bought the [product](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B010FDLGTU/) which stopped working after few months of using it and I'd like to contact the seller if they can exchange or repair it, but I couldn't find the option to do that.

I've tried so far:

- [How do you reply to a seller on Amazon?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/43604/22759), but there is no 'Contact seller' button,
- read [Contact Marketplace Sellers](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=3149541), but I couldn't find *Further Information* section with *Contact*,

  > **You can contact** a Marketplace Seller **both before and after placing an order**.

  Which is not true, because I don't see any option to do that. Either before or after the order.
- can't return, because *This item is no longer eligible for return.*

[image: Amazon - screenshot]
[image: Amazon - screenshot - This item is no longer eligible for return. The return window closed on 25 Mar 2016.]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [About Our Returns Policies](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=1161002) you can read:

> If a product becomes defective after 30 days you won't be able to create a returns label using our [Returns Support Centre](https://www.amazon.co.uk/returns) - you'll need to [Contact Us](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=502564). You may wish to visit the manufacturer's website or contact them directly as they may be able to offer troubleshooting and support with the issue you have with the product. Please see [Manufacturer Contact Details and After Sales Service](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200680110).

So basically you've to go to [*Contact Us*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/help/contact-us) page, select the order, then select as *Defective* and choose the form of contact, either by *E-mail*, *Phone* or *Chat*.

I've selected *Chat* and the replacement (free home collection) was arranged within few minutes.

Comment: Ah, you have to go to *Amazon's* contact us page.  Here it is for AmazonSmile: https://smile.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/contact-us